# Java - using streams to get list elements with a certain property

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two classes named `School` and `Student`, a set of Schools, a list of Students and two maps that hold the School's preferences in terms of students and vice versa:

```
Set<School> schoolSet = new TreeSet<>();
Collections.addAll(schoolSet, schools);

List<Student> studentList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(students));

Map<School, List<Student>> schoolPrefMap = new TreeMap<>();
Map<Student, List<School>> stdPrefMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I'm using different implementations because that's one of the tasks that I have to fulfill.

I'm trying to create a query using java streams that returns the Schools from the set that have a certain student as their top priority, so the index of that student should be 0 in the list of values for that specific school key.

I have an example of trying something similar, only getting the students who have at least a certain school(s) in his preferences

```
List<School> target = Arrays.asList(schools[0], schools[2]);

List<Student> result = studentList.stream()
        .filter(std -> stdPrefMap.get(std).containsAll(target))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I use streams to get the schools that have a given student as their top preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should accomplish what you specified:

```
Student target = ...
schoolSet.stream()
        .filter(school -> {
            List<Student> preferredStudents = schoolPrefMap.get(school);
            return !preferredStudents.isEmpty() && preferredStudents.get(0).equals(target);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

May I ask why you're not using a Map<School, PriorityQueue<Student>> and Map<Student, PriorityQueue<School>> (as it is perfectly suited for a case like this with rated preferences and using contains() / containsAll() on a list is not very efficient)?

In that case your code would look like this:

```
schoolSet.stream()
        .filter(school -> {
            Queue<Student> preferredStudents = schoolPrefMap.get(school);
            return !preferredStudents.isEmpty() && preferredStudents.peek().equals(target);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will find it helpful:

```
        List<School> schoolsWithTargetedStudentAsTopPref = schoolSet.stream()
            .filter(school -> schoolPrefMap.get(school).stream()
                    .findFirst()
                    .filter(student-> student.equals(target))
                    .map(optionalSchool -> !optionalSchool.isEmpty())
                    .get())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```